# Can Telegram Bot ask user to take picture from camera?

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

I want the bot to send an inline button of "sendPicture" and after clicking it the user can able to click picture from the camera and send it. In this process users not able to send the picture from their gallery. Is telethon support it or is there any other methods to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can just send them text asking nicely.

Comment: Is there any way to check source of the image sent to my bot, camera or gallery?